# Compiling CGAL with Emscripten for Web

Tags: c++, webassembly, cgal, emscripten, bitcode

I am trying to compile a CGAL application on the web using emscripten and web assembly. According to the emscripten documentation, external libraries must be compiled to bitcode first. I am not sure how to achieve that since CGAL has quite a large number of include files. Since I am a beginner in CGAL, I'd appreciate some help and guidance regarding the steps required for CGAL to web compilation.

Comment: CGAL is header-only, so you don't compile it separately.

Comment: Note that webassembly does not support rounding modes, which breaks most of CGAL.

Comment: @MarcGlisse since rounding modes are not supported in webassembly, could you suggest any other method to compile CGAL on web, or any alternative geometrical processing library which is easier to compile on web?

Comment: That's way too vague, CGAL does so many different things and I have no idea what small part of CGAL you care about...

Comment: @MarcGlisse I aim to use CGAL for reading/writing mesh files, hole detection and hole filling. Would the support of rounding modes be required for them? I'm a beginner and am unsure about this.